# Subtract all entries in one file from corresponding entries in another file without considering the missing value

Tags: linux, shell, awk, subtraction

I have two files with equal number of rows and columns. I would like to subtract the all entries in one file from the correspondng entries in another file without considering the missing values. e.g.

```
ifile1.txt    
3  5  2  2
1  ?  2  1
4  6  5  2
5  5  7  1

ifile2.txt
1  2  1  3
1  3  0  2
2  ?  5  1
0  0  1  1
```

Here "?" is the missing value and should not be considered in computation.

```
ofile.txt i.e. [(ifile1.txt) - (ifile2.txt)]
2.00  3.00  1.00 -1.00 
0.00  ?     2.00 -1.00 
2.00  ?     0.00  1.00 
5.00  5.00  6.00  0.00
```

I could able to do it **without any missing values** in following way. But can't able to succeed with a missing value like here "?".

```
paste ifile1.txt ifile2.txt > ifile3.txt
awk '{n=NF/2; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%5.2f ", $i-$(i+n); print ""}' ifile3.txt > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didn't test, but something like this should work

```
$ paste ifile1.txt ifile2.txt |
  awk -v q='?' '{n=NF/2; 
                 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                   printf "%5s ", (($i==q||$(i+n)==q)?q:$i-$(i+n)); 
                 print ""}' > ofile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. This is giving zero "0" values instead of missing "?" because of the formatting. So I used printf "%5s " instead of printf "%5.2f ". Working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I started playing around on how to read 2 files at the same time, ie. how to loose the `paste`. In awk:

```
$ cat mm.awk
NR>FNR { exit }                       # after file1 exit
{
    split($0,a," ")                   # split record from file1 to array a
    getline < ARGV[2]                 # read record from the file2
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # one for for both 
        printf "%s%s", ( a[i]!="?" && $i!="?" ? a[i]-$i : "?" ), ( i==NF ? ORS : OFS )
}                                     # on prev rec, if "?" in either, output "?"
```

Run it:

```
$ awk mm.awk file1 file2
2 3 1 -1
0 ? 2 -1
2 ? 0 1
5 5 6 0
```